# Бесконечное проигрывание аудио

Tags: javascript

Есть такой аудио скрипт при нажатии на который воспроизводиться аудио но когда я добавляю второй аудио файл он проигрывается бесконечно как это исправить?

```js
var tracks = ['audio/keysys.mp3', 'audio/key.mp3'];
var current = 0;
player.src = tracks[0];
player.onended = function() {
  current++;
  if (current >= tracks.length) current = 0;
  player.src = tracks[current];
  player.play();
}
```

Comment: Что такое "нажатие на скрипт"?

Comment: Вы уже получили шесть ответов на Ваши вопросы. То ответы, которые содержат решения, следует отметить "галочкой" слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все клипы по кругу:

```js
function playOnClick() {
  let tracks = [
    'https://www.kozco.com/tech/piano2.wav',
    'https://www.kozco.com/tech/organfinale.wav'
  ];
  let current = -1;
  let p = new Audio();
  (p.onended = function() {
    current = ++current % tracks.length;
    console.log(current, tracks[current]);
    p.src = tracks[current];
    p.play();
  })();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playOnClick()">Play</button>
```

Все клипы один раз:

```js
function playOnClick() {
  let tracks = [
    'https://www.kozco.com/tech/piano2.wav',
    'https://www.kozco.com/tech/organfinale.wav'
  ];
  let current = -1;
  let p = new Audio();
  (p.onended = function() {
    if (++current < tracks.length) {
      p.src = tracks[current];
      p.play();
    }
    console.log(current, tracks[current]);
  })();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playOnClick()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Тоже проигрывается бесконечно при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @ChelovekMira Что "проигрывается бесконечно"? Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе, а потом - кнопку "Play".

Comment: Нажимал и что дальше оно проигрывается по кругу бесконенчо

Comment: @ChelovekMira А должно как быть?

Comment: По одному разу проиграться

Comment: @ChelovekMira Второй пример в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо работает

Comment: @ChelovekMira Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Подскажи а как сделать так что бы звук проигрывался только при включении

Comment: @ChelovekMira При включении чего?

Comment: Я добавил этот скрипт в кнопку включения картинки как сделать так что бы звуки воспроизводились только при включении картинки

Comment: @ChelovekMira Мне сквозь монитор плохо видны Ваши мысли, и я понятия не имею, о какой картинке речь, и что значит "включение картинки".

Comment: Обычная кнопка включить отключить function TotalLength() {
  this.textContent = this.textContent === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off'; var line = document.querySelector('.content');
  line.style.display = getComputedStyle(line).display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}